# Discord_Components - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, discord, modulenotfounderror

I'm having a Problem with Discord Components.
This is the Error:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\Daniel Zink\Documents\Coding\VIsual Studio Code\Virus\test.py", line 3, in <module> from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_components'` 
The Problem is I have done:
pip install discord components
And everything was installed correctly.

The following code is the import:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle
```

I tried:

1. `pip install discord --upgrade`
2. `pip install discord components --upgrade`
3. `[python path] -m pip install discord-components`
4. `Install Newest Python Version`

Answer (score 1):

You might have different python versions installed. If that's the case, download the library specifically for the python version you are trying to use.